# Can I use VOLATILE TABLE in SSIS ADO NET SOURCE if not is there any alternative?

Tags: ssis, teradata, volatile

I have Teradata as source and SQL  server as Destination. I am trying to pull data from Teradata and load into SQL server using SSIS Package. I only have ready access to Teradata where I can Create VOLATILE TABLE as temp table and use in my select query. Do i have any other alternative?

Comment: What does "Ready Access" mean? You can run a SELECT statement on Teradata, why would you need any more access then that to pull data into your SQL Server? What purpose would a volatile table serve you here and why are you worried that it isn't enough for your needs?

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I mean to say I have read access to teradata db. I am trying use query in ADO NET Source SSIS. but volatile table doesn't work.